# How to push with git to github on Windows?

Tags: git, github

Simply, I can't:

- HTTPS push

  - Eclipse git plugin doesn't support it ([here](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2010/08/09/git-https/))
  - msygit UI consumes all existing memory and hangs
  - turtoisegit consumes all existing memory and hangs
- SSH push

  - generated the keypair, but it turns out github does not support putty, only ssh
  - I don't want to install cygwin

Comment: Putty is an SSH program for Windows, so GitHub does indeed accept it. However, msysGit often has trouble with SSH, so generally it works better using other protocols like HTTPS.

Comment: Sounds like your msysGit installation (which is used/required for TortoiseGit too) is having a serious issue. Is there a chance that you have some different versions of the msysGit DLLs elsewhere in your path, like the Windows folder? Also, the installer gives you 2 options for SSH--either use the built-in SSH.EXE (iffy) or Putty's PLINK.EXE (better) for SSH--can you try using the other option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, using the Git bash of msysgit worked:

```
git push <address>
```

(the GUI didn't work, even after reinstalling msysgit with different options)

Answer (score 2):

[Getting Started with Git and GitHub on Windows](http://kylecordes.com/2008/git-windows-go) has the answer and will guide you through all the steps to start using Git and GitHub from Windows. In a nutshell: install [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) (Git for Windows) and use it to generate the key.

Comment: I allready have a key which works on Linux. Where should put it?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that Putty generates a keypair in a different format than OpenSSH does. However, the Putty key generation tool lets you open one of its keys and can then produce an **OpenSSH-compatible public key**. It looks like this:

[image: Putty key gnerator]

You should be able to upload that to GitHub.

Comment: that's good, but it still doesn't work with putty. It says "No authentication method available". Anyway, I made it work via the Git Bash.

Comment: Okay -- good that you got it working. I actually don't use Git so I haven't tested it with GitHub -- I just once had to use a Putty-generated SSH key pair with a Linux server running OpenSSH.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions).

Comment: I don't think that will help him any, since Git Extensions requires that you have msysGit installed--and that's clearly not working here.