# how to make windows remember my passphrase key?

Tags: windows, git, ssh, github

Each time I want to push my file to GitHub, Git always shows me notification to enter my passphrase. For example,

> *Enter passphrase for key /c/Users/.ssh/id_rsa*

I want my Git to remember the passphrase for me. How should I possibly do that on Windows 7? I've already read the help page here http://help.github.com/ssh-key-passphrases/. It seems only available for Mac / Linux.

Comment: What are you using for SSH?
If Putty, it includes pageant, which you can use as a key agent in windows.
Then you would need to set up the GIT_SSH environment variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remember Password, Git bash under windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727555/remember-password-git-bash-under-windows)

Answer (score 13):

I believe if you use msysgit then you can install (or maybe it comes already installed) openssh.

With openssh you can use the command line program `ssh-add` to add you key once and remember it:

```
ssh-add /c/Users/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: It only remembers this for a session

Answer (score 8):

After spending ample time on going through many articles and stackoverflow answers I found following approach working out for me for Windows.

1. **Enable the OpenSSH Authentication Agent service** and make it start automatically. Refer [this article](https://dev.to/solrevdev/windows-does-not-remember-git-password-lmh)
2. **Add your SSH key** to the agent with `ssh-add`
3. **Add an environment variable** for GIT_SSH - `setx GIT_SSH C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`
4. **Config git** - `git config --global core.sshCommand C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe`

4th step was the gem for me ;)

Comment: On Windows, you can also use the ` Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic` command in PowerShell for the first step

Comment: Anecdotally, environment variables can also be set with `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("GIT_SSH", "C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)`, though user-scoped environment variables require a new shell session because unlinke process-scoped environment variables, they are not loaded immediately

Answer (score 0):

One of these questions surely contains valid answers:
[How to push with git to github on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644888/how-to-push-with-git-to-github-on-windows)

[How do I store a password for my key so I can commit and pull from repository when using git on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625148/how-do-i-store-a-password-for-my-key-so-i-can-commit-and-pull-from-repository-wh)

Or you could use putty like they do in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370030/why-git-cant-remember-my-passphrase-under-windows/4356869#4356869)

Comment: I'm voting for the last link.

Comment: So great answer with expired links. Was it so much work to paste the text here? Now it's useless: Error 503 Service Unavailable

Comment: No need to be cynical, Google found me a replacement ... check it again